# Splitting of cell arrays according to a value and storing the indoces in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, split, matlab-compiler

I am stuck with a problem statement in MATLAB. I have a matrix H containing only 0 and 1 and I need to seperate the rows and columns into different cell array. From there I need to make another set which contains the value of each indices in row and column containing 1. The index numbering should be unique. Could someone please help me with it.I need individual set containing only the value of rows with 1 and column with 1. Any help would be appreciated.

I have the following matrix with me:

```
H= [1 1 0 0 1;1 0 1 0 1;1 1 0 0 0;0 0 0 1 0];
    

rows = num2cell(H,2); % rows of the matrix
columns = num2cell(H,1); % columns of the matrix
```

Comment: Do you mean you need something like `[row,col]=ind2sub(size(H),find(H));[row col],`? Or would it be `unique(row),unique(col),`?

Comment: @Vicky [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) will happily give the the row and column numbers rather than the index: `[row, col] = find(H);`

Comment: @beaker You're right -- I'm used to working with multidimensional arrays, but in this case your approach is far better.

Comment: Hi, @Vicky I am able to get the row and column index by                            [row column] = find (H == 1);  however they return the value of the index having 1. I need to further find the intersection of rows with some other parameter for which I need unique row and column and also the value 1 in them. This I am unable to get. But thanks for the tips